# Ergodic Discrete spectrum(pure point spectrum)

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

We have an ergodic measure preserving system such that there is an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ which consists of eigenfunctions of T. This is just a definition of discrete spectrum ergodic system.

How can I show that there is a sequence ${n_k}$ of integers such that
$||{T^{n_k}f-f}||_2$  goes to zero for $f \in L^2$?

Any hint or answer would be appreciated. Also, is the added assumption of ergodicity needed?

Comment: What is $T$? Is it the induced transformation on $L^2(X,\mu)$? Don't you want to apply it to some function?

Comment: Oh! My mistake. I edited.

Comment: Right. T is the induced transformation :)